# Where to set RemoteRootDirectory to compile iOS C++ Shared Library in VS 2017

Tags: xamarin, shared-libraries, visual-studio-2017

I get the error:
Error   MSB4044 The "VCRemoteClean" task was not given a value for the required parameter "RemoteRootDirectory".

My Environment consists of a PC with Visual Studio 2017 (professional)
with the Xamarin build agent successfully linked to the MAC

My Mac has Xcode 8.3.3 and Visual Studio 2017 for the MAC

My project is a Xamarin forms with a PCL. It compiles for iOS and successfully creates an IPA file
I add a C++ cross platform shared project. If I try to build or compile the iOS project I get the error above.

I looked in the file iOS.Common.targets located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Application Type\iOS\1.0

It references the environment variable RemoteRootDirectory. I am not sure where it should be set.

Thanks in advance for any help,
Scott

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. So do you have a solution so far?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the reason for the error is that `vcremote` isn't connected to a remote MacOS computer. Here is a VS developer community answer that can be found when searching for this error:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/43015/error-msb4044-the-task-was-not-given-a-value-for-t.html
The author itself answered:

> I was able to set it in iOS.Common.targets to
>   /Users//xcremote/. After that the real error became more
>   clear. vcremote was not connected.
>
> See here on how to set it up:
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt147405.aspx

The article links to a VS 2015 article, though. The latest VS 2019 link is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/cross-platform/install-and-configure-tools-to-build-using-ios?view=vs-2019&redirectedfrom=MSDN